# Javascript display numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a webpage where the user inputs the limit for a counter, which starts at 0. When the user enters a number and clicks the button, the web page will display all the numbers from 0 up to the limit entered.

The following is the JavaScript code I have so far however it wont run properly.

```js
function display() {
  var num = document.getElementbyId("UserIN").value;
  num = parseInt(num);
  var counter = 0;
  while (counter <= num) {
    document.getElementById("outdisplay").innerHTML += counter + "<br/>";
    counter += 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="UserIN">
<button onclick="display()">Run</button>
<div id="outdisplay"></div>
```

Comment: it is actually `getElementById` at line 2 of javascript code instead of `getElementbyId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function display(inputElement, outputElement) { 
    var num = parseInt(inputElement.value); 
    var counter = 0; 
    // Loop from 0 to number
    for (counter; counter < num; counter++) {
        outputElement.innerHTML += `${counter}<br/>`;
    }
}
```

Is that what you want?